# Javascript - ensure geocoder loop finishes before it's nested loop, causing issue with markerCluster

Tags: javascript, google-maps, loops

I tried to pose a similar question, and received no help. [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476444/not-all-markers-in-markercluster-are-using-the-markcluster)

Made a little progress, found where the issue is, but still not understanding the correct solution. I have read every SO question about this, and understand there are similar questions, but I still have not been able to figure it out, so constructive feedback is appreciated :)

SET UP: Some users have a lat/lng saved, and some with just a location.
Before plotting them on the map, it needs to run through a geocoder loop to create a lat/lng for any user with just location (ex. "New York, NY, United States"). After all the users have a lat/lng, I want their marker to be added to the marker cluster.

ISSUE: The customMarkers created in the geocoder loop are running after the initMap() function is complete. I have tried it all in one loop (see code in the link above). Still the geocoder loop was finishing after the other loop - meaning the markers were created after the markerCluster, and therefore were not clustering. So, now I'm thinking to break apart the code, and make sure each function is done, before running the next.

I've tried a few ways. For example like this:

`$.when(getMatches(map)).then(clusterUp(map, markers));`

The customMarkers from the geocoder are still console logging AFTER the entire initMap()function is done, and now the markercluster is undefined at the end of initMap() function.

**How do I ensure the markerCluster is only created after all the customMarkers are created?**

```
var lat
var lng
var userLocation
var userId
var markers = []
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

function getMatches(map) {
    var matches = $.getJSON('get_json_matches', function(matches){
        var matches = matches
        for(i=0; i < 11; i++) {
          function (i) {

            var userId = 0
            var lat = matches[i][4];
            var lng = matches[i][5];
            var userId = matches[i][3];
            var userLocation = matches[i][2]

            //If the user only has a location, make up a lat/lng     
            if (lat === null) {
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': userLocation }, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var lat = (results[0].geometry.location.lat()) + (userId * .0001);

                        var lng = (results[0].geometry.location.lng()) + (userId * .0001);
                        var marker = new CustomMarker(
                            new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
                            map 
                        );
                    }  
                });    
            } else {
                    var marker = new CustomMarker(
                        new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
                        map
                    );       
            }
            markers.push(marker);   
          }).call(this, i);

        }

    return markers

})
}



function clusterUp(map, markers) {
    console.log(markers)
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'})
    return markerCluster
    console.log(markerCluster)
}


function initMap() {
    var newYork = {lat: 40.7127837, lng: -74.00594130000002};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("user-matches-map"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(newYork),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: googleMapStyle
    });
    var markerCluster
    $.when(getMatches(map)).then(clusterUp(map, markers));
    console.log(markers)
    console.log(markerCluster) 
}

initMap();
```

I would really appreciate some constructive feedback. I have been researching this for over a day, and think I'm missing a fundamental concept. Thank you!!

Comment: If you really want to wait for all async calls to be finished before executing some other code, you may want to look into Promises and he `Promise.all` method.

Comment: @jcaron thank you for that suggestion! I have not heard of Promise.all before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to the MarkerClusterer in the global scope, then add the markers that result from the calls to the geocoder in the geocoder's callback function when/where they are available.

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': userLocation }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var lat = (results[0].geometry.location.lat()) + (userId * .0001);

        var lng = (results[0].geometry.location.lng()) + (userId * .0001);
        var marker = new CustomMarker(
            new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
            map 
        );
        // add each marker created by the geocoder callback to the clusterer as it is created.
        markerCluster.addMarker(marker);

    }  
}); 

// global scope
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [],
    {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});

function clusterUp(map, markers) {
    console.log(markers)
    // add all the markers that don't require geocoding to the clusterer
    markerCluster.addMarkers(markers);
    console.log(markerCluster)
}
```

Comment: When I put `var markerCluster ` outside the whole function, I get an error saying `setMap: not an instance of Map;` -- but when I put that inside of the getMatches(map) it works perfectly! I'm accepting this answer, since it lead me to the solution with a minor tweak. Thank you very much!!